# Load dynamic Vue routes from json file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

**Context:**

I am building a Vue SPA where I set most of my content in a json file during the build of the application (different content can be served based on environment variables). **I need my vue router to be set with some content from that json file!**

The problem I am having is that the route is already set before the json content is available. I have read many related solutions, but cannot get anything to work...

---

**Code:**

Completely stripped version of my code to understand my current setup:

My main application file `app.js`:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  methods: {
    async storeStaticContent() {
      // This is where I fetch the content and write it away in the store.
      const response = await fetch(`/static/content.json`);
      const json = await response.json();
      this.$store.commit(MUTATIONS.SET_CONTENT, json);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.storeStaticContent();
  },
});
```

My router setup `router.js`:

```
export const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      // The route I need to populate with a string that I write away to the store in my app.js
      {
        path: `/${store.getters.mainEntity}`,
        name: store.getters.mainEntity,
        component: EntityPage,
      },
      {
        path: '/*',
        name: 'not found',
        component: NotFound,
      },
    }
  ],
  base: '/',
  fallback: true,
});
```

Two lines from `package.json` for the versions I am using:

```
"vue": "^2.6.10",
"vue-router": "^3.1.3",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My prefered way to do this is to download your `JSON` first, than create a router and **after that** you can create main Vue instance passing the router instance in...

*Note: I'm leaving out the Vuex stuff for simplicity...*

`router.js`

```js
export async createRouter() {
    const response = await fetch(`/static/content.json`)
    const json = await response.json();
    const routes = ...generate routes here from the json object
    return new VueRouter({
      routes,
      // other options
    })
}
```

`main.js`

```js
import createRouter from `router`

Vue.use(VueRouter);

createRouter().then((router) => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Michal! Your suggestion worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for addRoutes method:

[router.addRoutes - Vue Router API](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes)

If all is fine in your store this should do:

```js
  methods: {
    async storeStaticContent() {
      // This is where I fetch the content and write it away in the store.
      const response = await fetch(`/static/content.json`);
      const json = await response.json();
      this.$store.commit(MUTATIONS.SET_CONTENT, json);
      this.addRoute();
    },
    addRoute: function() {
      this.$router.addRoutes(
        [{
          path: `/${store.getters.mainEntity}`,
          name: store.getters.mainEntity,
          component: EntityPage,
        }]
      );
    }
  },
```

Comment: I will look into it tomorrow first thing (have had a frustrating night already). The reason I haven't gone for addRoutes yet is that I thought that it might nog work when a user goes directly to that route. Is it already available for that user when it is set during the created() lifecycle hook?

Comment: But Router evaluates the routes "in-order" so his fall-back route will take priority over the new route. Unless he creates Router with completely empty routes. Is this even possible ? I don't know. It seems easier and more clear to download data 1st and create router (and main Vue instance) after that....

Comment: Thanks again Yuri, I decided to go with Michal's answer, for I for-saw some possible new issues that could arise from using addRoutes. One of them pointed out by Michal here too.

Comment: @MichalLevý  Thanks for mentioning the fall-back route.  That was preciously my problem.  The 404PageNotFound page was catching the routes I added after creating the router.  I think I will follow your suggestion above.  Thank you!